# How to run a piece of code a variable number of time?

Tags: python, function, loops

Here in the below given code I am able to run it once but I want to ask the user how many times they want to run it then the code would run that many times. For e.g the user wants to test two cases then they would enter.

```
2 --> Test cases
5 12
1 2 3 7 5
10 15
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Code:

```
def subsum(arr,n,sum):
    for i in range(n):
        currsum=arr[i]
        j=i+1
        while j<=n:
            if currsum==sum:
                print ("Sum found between")
                print("indexes %d and %d"%( i, j-1))
                return 1
            if currsum>sum or j==n:
                break
            currsum=currsum+arr[j]
            j+=1
    print ("No subarray found")
    return 0

# Driver program
n, sum = map(int, input().split())
arr=list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
subsum(arr,n,sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `for` or `while` loop

```
def subsum(arr,n,sum):
for i in range(n):
    currsum=arr[i]
    j=i+1
    while j<=n:
        if currsum==sum:
            print ("Sum found between")
            print("indexes %d and %d"%( i, j-1))
            return 1
        if currsum>sum or j==n:
            break
        currsum=currsum+arr[j]
        j+=1
print ("No subarray found")
return 0
# Driver program

if __name__ =='__main__':
    t = int(input())
    for _ in range(t):
        n, sum = map(int, input().split())
        arr=list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
        res = subsum(arr,n,sum)
        print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help i am still new to using this site so i don't know much.

Comment: @Codenoob if you want all result to print after giving the input then store it in the list and then print the list